# Solve $\tanh(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x \tanh(x)}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that : $$\tanh(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x \tanh (x)}$$ has one positive root.
Let $f(x)=\tanh(x)$ and Let $g(x)=x + \frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{x \tanh(x)}$
I think that is enough to show that $f(x)$ is increasing and that $g(x)$ is decreasing .

How Can I prove that $g(x)$ is decreasing ?

I calculated $g'(x)=\tanh^2(x) (x^2 -x-1)-\tanh(x) + x =0$

And How I find the point of intersection or at least prove that it is in the first quadrant ?

Thank you ...

Comment: It's not quite enough to show that $f(x)$ is increasing and $g(x)$ is decreasing.  The same can be said of $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = -e^x$, but those two have $0$ points of intersection.  You'll also want to show that there exists a value of $x$ for which $f(x) \le g(x)$.

Comment: Your RHS is not defined at $x = 0$ are you restricting the domain to $x > 0$?

Comment: I also don't think your RHS is monotonic for $x > 0$.

Comment: Furthermore, what makes you think this equation has a positive root?

Comment: i think a numerical method will help here

Comment: I know that the root is positive by graphing the two functions

Comment: Plotting the function suggests that there is *no* possitive root of $f(x)=\tanh x-x-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x \tanh x}$. There is, though, a positive root of the *derivative* $f'(x)$, which leads to a maximum $x^*$, but $f(x^*)$ seems to be negative...

Comment: There is some thing wrong in my calculation